# tcpdump on Android X86 via Android Emulator

Tags: android, root, tcpdump

I'm trying to get tcpdump working on my Android emulator and running into problems in every direction it seems. On my Android tablet which is already rooted I've got things working fine, but would like to do it from my laptop as well.

So I can adb root of course and then shell to the device, but there's no actual su program (...or so I thought...) so Android apps themselves can't seem to run as root. I wanted to run BusyBox on my emulator to get a set of my usual tools on there, the installer failed saying the app wasn't root, as to be expected. Installing SuperSu fails because it says su is not there, even though I have root on the device, and there also happens to be a su sitting in /system/xbin so I don't know why I'm getting an inconsistent error message.

After that though, I'll still need to install tcpdump. There's an ARM binary but I haven't found one for Android x86. Running from source even in the /data/local/ container it gives me a file not found for ./configure error when trying to run. I also want to have apt-get on my machine anyway, so would installing Debian side-by-side with Android be the best route?

Comment: for tcpdump please read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439997/cross-compile-tcpdump-for-x86